# 'ng serve' failure on Covalent Quickstart under Windows

Tags: angular, teradata-covalent

I am trying to serve Covalent Quickstart on windows but get an error indicating that  there is no such file or directory, all details below.

Any insight greatly appreciated:)

Executing 'ng serve' on windows 10 results in the following error message,

ERROR in ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\C\covalent\src\app\app.module.ts'

The angular-cli app resides in 'C:\C\covalent', seems like there is an additional 'C' prefixed by the ng serve process, not sure where this originates from though.

so output is as follows,

**C:\covalent>ng serve
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

```
Date: 2018-07-20T04:29:03.325Z
Hash: 761529610e6f4f77920b
Time: 6136ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.88 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 657 bytes 
[initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] 
[rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 20.8 kB [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 794 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 325 kB [initial] [rendered]

 ERROR in ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 
 'C:\C\covalent\src\app\app.module.ts'
 i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.**
```

My environment is as follows,

```
C:\covalent>ng --version

Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.2
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package Version
@angular-devkit/architect 0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular 0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer 0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core 0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics 0.6.1
@angular/cli 6.0.1
@angular/material 6.0.1
@ngtools/json-schema 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack 6.0.8
@schematics/angular 0.6.1
@schematics/update 0.6.1
ng-packagr 2.4.2
rxjs 6.0.0
typescript 2.7.2
webpack 4.8.3
```

Comment: Looks like it's [happened before](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10214). Try removing node_modules, lock files and do a fresh install. If not, maybe bump it back to a previous version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I deleted lock file, removed node_modules folder and executed 'npm i' to reinstall all dependencies. No luck though, issue is still there. Seems like I'll have to downgrade angular cli now... any other ideas or did I miss a step above?

Comment: Can't say Del, not a windows user. Try creating a brand new project, and if it still happens I'd open an issue on github.

Comment: Same issue here.